# How could I go about making a app for my blog?

Tags: android, wordpress

I currently have a wordpress blog: www.androidfunandmore.info and I was wondering how do I go about making an android app for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the Mobile plugin to word press and then create a bookmark to it.  This makes a web app (not a native app), but it looks good and it's easy.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-edition/